# How do I find the value of X cells after a matched contains with xpath and lxml

Tags: html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I have a document with multiple rows that has a value in the 4th TD element that I can't figure out how to retrieve.  There is nothing unique in the tags so I have to match based on the word TOTAL, and then get the value I need from the 4th TD in the existing row.  This is one TR for illustration:

```
<TR>
<TD ALIGN="right" COLSPAN="30" bgcolor=d8caca><div class=small4>SECTION TOTAL</div></TD>
<TD ALIGN="right" COLSPAN="8" bgcolor=d8caca> &nbsp; </TD>
<TD ALIGN="right" COLSPAN="13" bgcolor=gold><div class=small4>  11.907531</div> 
</TD>
<TD ALIGN="right" COLSPAN="13" bgcolor=gold><div class=small4>     $773.10</div></TD>
</TR>
```

I want to match on the word "TOTAL" and then get the value exactly three cells later, or in this case, $773.10.

This successfully gathers each of the "TOTAL" text in an array without issue:

```
titles = tree.xpath("//tr/td[contains(., 'TOTAL')]//text()")
```

However, I am unable to get the values in the last  element.  I've tried numerous variations of the following searching for the TOTAL and then trying to use following or following-sibling to no avail:

```
totals = tree.xpath("//tr/td[contains(., 'TOTAL')]/../following::td[4]/div/text()")
```

...but I either get an array of the non-breakable space from the immediate next TD after the TOTAL, no data at all, or "element" references that when expanded to text are null.  How do I properly get the value inside td[4] in the existing TR after the contains is matched?

I am trying to get every occurence, not just one, so that the titles and totals arrays are a 1:1 match.  If there is a way to do a key=>value pairing that'd be even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `following-sibling` axis to get `td` located after `td` that contain text "TOTAL" in the same parent, and then filter the result further to get only the last of such `td` using predicate `[last()]`, then return the child `div/text()` :

```
query = "//tr/td[contains(., 'TOTAL')]/following-sibling::td[last()]/div/text()"
titles = tree.xpath(query)
```

xpathtester demo: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/5cf0aa473d030da66de1bec73bcb8795

Comment: this worked.  I swear I tried this exact approach without success so i'm not sure what I did wrong when it didn't work.  Thank you.